# Texshop not writing section headings in beamer

Tags: beamer

[image: enter image `description here]I'm using the  boadilla theme to create slides within a beamer document class – and I'm using Texshop on Mac OS X to compile, but Texshop won't generate section headings when producing the PDF. What am I doing wrong?

Example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}


\title[Example]{}
\author[Joe Doe]{}

\begin{document}

\section{Example section}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Example slide}
  Some text.
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you expect? For me your example works as expected (by an experienced LaTeX user).

Comment: I thought the section title would be printed somewhere. (Sorry, I'm blind, so I rely on other people's descriptions of what the visual output should look like. Maybe I have the wrong expectations?)

Comment: The section title shall NOT be printed. It's just structuring the text. If you want it to be printed you have to set the frame title.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option for you: This environment `sframe` will print your section and (if not empty) subsection title as frame title.

```
\newenvironment{sframe}{% new environment: frame with auto frametitle
        \begin{frame}{\thesection.~\insertsection}%
            \ifx\insertsubsection\@empty%
            \else%
                \framesubtitle{\thesection.\thesubsection.~\insertsubsection}%
            \fi%
    }{\end{frame}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you want the section to appear, so here a few possibilities.

**Possibility 1:**

As an individual page at the start of the section

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\title{Example}
\author{Joe Doe}


\begin{document}

\section{Example section}

\begin{frame}
    \sectionpage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Example slide}
  Some text.
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of section page]

If this should be automatic for every section, try

```
\AtBeginSection[]{%
    \begin{frame}
        \sectionpage
    \end{frame}
}
```

**Possibility 2:**

A navigation on the top of the frame, showing all sections with the current one highlighted. This is actually part of many beamer themes, so easiest would be to just add one of them

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\title{Example}
\author{Joe Doe}


\begin{document}

\section{Example section}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example slide}
    Some text.
  \end{frame}

\section{Example section2}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example slide}
    Some text.
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of headline with sections]

**Possibility 3:**

Just the current section/subsection in the headline is actually a build in option (`secheader`) of the theme you choose:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
\title{Example}
\author{Joe Doe}


\begin{document}

\section{Example section}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example slide}
    Some text.
  \end{frame}

\section{Example section2}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example slide}
    Some text.
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: image with current section in the headline]

**Possibility 4:**

As part of the frametitle -- this can also be done automatically, here just as a proof of concept

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\title{Example}
\author{Joe Doe}


\begin{document}

\section{Example section}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\insertsectionhead{} -- Example slide}
    Some text.
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]